# How do I stop duplication of an object in localStorage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I've a component call KeywordLocation.js, and It has one prop named location.
this component is a mapped array and on click I want to save the object of location in localStorage. I created here an empty array and pushing the object on every click. For now I'm getting 5 mapped location objects. when I click on any of them, it saves the object but on 2nd click it doesn't stop duplicating the object. How do I stop this duplication?

```
searchedLocation.map((location, i) => {
  return (
    <KeywordLocation
      setShowMap={props.setShowMap}
      location={location}
      key={i}
      getPositionFromManualSearch={props.getPositionFromManualSearch}
    />
  );
});
```

KeywordLocation.js

```
const Component = ({ location }) => {
  let allSearchedLocations = [];

  const redirectToMap = async () => {
    allSearchedLocations.push(location);
    allSearchedLocations = allSearchedLocations.concat(
      JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("recent_location_searched") || "[]")
    );
    const previousLocation = JSON.parse(
      localStorage.getItem("recent_location_searched")
    );
    console.log(previousLocation);
    localStorage.setItem(
      "recent_location_searched",
      JSON.stringify(allSearchedLocations)
    );
  };

  return (
    <div onClick={() => redirectToMap()} className="pt-md cursor-pointer">
      <p>{location.structured_formatting.main_text}</p>
      <p className="text-xs border-b border-black pb-md ">
        {location.description}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Could you clarify "it doesn't stop duplicating the object" ? From what I understand each time the div is clicked a new entry is added. If you click two times on the same location it's added two times, it sounds expected?

Comment: yes, thanks. how can I make a unique array or something to stop the duplication?

Answer (score 0):

Are you entirely sure the duplication is ocurring on local storage?

As long as you use the same key, `recent_location_searched`, there will be only one value stored on that key. Take a look at the "Storage" tab on your browser's debug console to see what's actually being stored.

All evidence seems to point that the duplication is ocurring at the `searchLocations` variable, not at`localStorage`.

You might try to add some conditional logic that prevents you from pushing to `searchLocations` if the location is the same as the one on the last item on the array.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not related to `localStorage` but more about the usage of the array structure. You could rely on JavaScripts object to store the unique values. You lose the insertion order but you can create a companion array that keep a reference to the order.

```
const Test = ({ location }) => {
  const redirectToMap = () => {
    const locations =
      JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("recent_location_searched")) || {};

    locations[location.name] = location;

    localStorage.setItem("recent_location_searched", JSON.stringify(locations));
  };

  return (
    <div onClick={() => redirectToMap()} className="pt-md cursor-pointer">
      <p>{location.name}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const data =
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("recent_location_searched")) || {};
  
    return (
    <div>
      <div className="App">
        {[
          { name: "location1" },
          { name: "location3" },
          { name: "location2" }
        ].map((location) => (
          <Test key={location.name} location={location} />
        ))}
      </div>

      <ul>
        {Object.values(data).map((location) => (
          <li key={location.name}>Saved {location.name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: getting ```Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): JSON.parse(...) is not iterable (cannot read property null)```

Comment: It means the value is null at the beginning, you have to handle this corner case by returning an empty array if it the storage is empty.

Comment: I was a bit too optimistic on how to use a `Set`. I updated the logic and now it should work as expected. Don't forget to clear the `localStorage` first because we may have something not parsable and it will thrown a new error.

Comment: @SamuelVaillant thanks, not getting any error but on 2nd click it still adds the duplicate object in storage.

Comment: Well a Set will work only with primitive or object references (I did my small implementation with `strings` but your location variable is an object). If the ref changes at each render indeed you have multiple entries. A simpler solution is to rely on a map then. I updated the code.

Comment: @SamuelVaillant sorry for the late response, no I used ```Object.values(data)``` but it still printing the double values.

Comment: Strange. Here is a quick example with the code above in [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-haze-rotsf). You can click multiple times on the `div` and reload the page the `localStorage` only have a single entry per location.